# Biginteger in Schema Builder Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, biginteger

How can I do a biginteger type in a table row with Schema builder in Laravel 4.

Thx for all.

Comment: re read the faq please http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @anakata, that isn't helpful to Antonio. If you're making a point, make it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bigInteger() is present in Laravel 4's Schema Builder, so your migration should look like this:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->bigInteger('human_lives');
    });
}
```